# Why is the one-dimensional formal group law always commutative on a reduced ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

A one-dimensional formal group law is basically just a choice of a power series which satisfies several axioms.

Suppose that our choice is $F_1$ in variables $x,y$. then $F_1$ is in form of $F_1(x,y) = x+y+H.O.C$, To prove that it is commutative, then $F_1$ should somehow be of a symmetric form, why is this true?